# JS: dropdown content can't be displayed when navbar is fixed

Tags: javascript

Once I added the line position:fixed into the .navbar to fix my navbar, the dropdown content could not be displayed anymore. Any Idea, how it could be and how can I fix the navbar in a right way here?

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .navbar {    
     position: fixed;       
     width: 200px;   
     overflow: hidden;  
     background-color: #333;  
    }   
   .dropdown {  
    float: left;  
    overflow: hidden;  
   }  
  .dropdown-content {  
    display: none;  
    position: absolute;   
  }  
 .dropdown-content a {  
   text-decoration: none;  
   text-align: left;  
  }  
 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {  
  display: block;  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should remove overflow:hidden on .navbar

Comment: Great. Thank you very much for your quick help. It helps me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't add `overflow: hidden` in `.navbar`, the right way:

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;  
  background-color: #333;
}
```

[See the demo](https://codepen.io/ricosmall/pen/mdJwMdy)